# Split home partition into 2 (xfs on LVM)

Tags: lvm, size, xfs

I am using centos 7 and I have a /home mounted on an xfs filesystem on a dedicated LVM partition.

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home        782G   34M  782G   1% /home
```

I want to split this partition to 2 partitions, one of them to be mounted on /home, is there any way I can do this while the OS is running normaly, like I don't have to boot into livecd.

Comment: What fs is on /home?

Comment: @Artur Szymczak, its xfs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual approach to splitting a filesystem would be to shrink the existing filesystem and create a new one in the space which is made free.

However, you cannot shrink an xfs filesystem.  According to the FAQ *[Is there a way to make a XFS filesystem larger or smaller?](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_Is_there_a_way_to_make_a_XFS_filesystem_larger_or_smaller.3F)*:

> You can NOT make a XFS partition smaller online. The only way to shrink is to do a complete dump, `mkfs` and restore.
>
> An XFS filesystem may be enlarged by using [`xfs_growfs(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man8/xfs_info.8.html).
>
> If using partitions, you need to have free space after this partition to do so. Remove partition, recreate it larger with the exact same starting point. Run `xfs_growfs` to make the partition larger. Note - editing partition tables is a dangerous pastime, so back up your filesystem before doing so.
>
> Using XFS filesystems on top of a volume manager makes this a lot easier.

The size of your current `/home` is small (as filesystems go, nowadays), so the approach would be to

- backup your `/home` (on some *other* filesystem or computer)
- delete the `xfs` filesystem
- create the new filesystems to your taste
- restore the backup

Further reading:

- [XFS FAQ](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ)

Comment: ...you did not explain how to perform the LVM split, maybe he doesn't even care about preserving data on /home, or the xfs filesystem itself

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce a *logical volume* size with `lvreduce`, for example say you want to create another 10G partition you can first free up the space needed with:

```
lvreduce -L -10G /dev/mapper/centos-home
```

and then create a new *LV* with

```
lvcreate -L 10G -n share centos
```

this will create a `/dev/mapper/centos-share` device of 10G

As mentioned by Thomas Dickey, the resize operation will destroy your filesystem, so you may want to backup anything valuable you have there. Both logical volumes should be formatted afterwards with the desired filesystems.